# How to use Google Sheets as read-only database for Angular, without making the sheet public

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use Google Sheets document as read-only database for my angular application.
I tried some methods to do that, but the problem with all of these methods is that they require the Sheet to be shared publicly (anyone with the link can access the sheet). But what I want is to share it with specific user using Service Account through credentials.

- I'm using Angular 14
- There is no reference to Angular in [Google Sheets for Developers](https://developers.google.com/sheets).

If you know any solution or come across an article about this topic, please share it with me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you'll need to take in order to read from Google Sheets into Angular:

**Step 1: Prepare your Google Sheet**

1.) Make sure ALL the cells in your sheet are formatted as "Plain text". To do this, click in the upper-left corner of the sheet nexus where the rows and columns intersect to select all cells, then select `Format > Number > Plain text` from the top menu.

[image]

2.) Go to Share, then under "General Access", select "Anyone with the link", then click `Done`. I believe in your case that this step is optional, since you do not want the sheet to be public.

3.) Go to `File > Share > Publish to web` in the top menu. Set the scope of what you want to publish, then click `Publish`. Unfortunately in your case, this step is NOT optional!

**Step 2: Fetch the Google Sheet Data**

Use the following code example to fetch the raw data from your Google Sheet as plain text:

```
const docId = '1vLjJqvLGdaS39ccsvoU58kEWXngzV_VXtto07Ki6qVo';
const sheetId = ''; // to get a specific sheet by ID, use '&gid=###'
const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${docId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json${sheetId}`;
this.http.get(url, {
   responseType: 'text',
}).subscribe((response: string): void => {
   console.log(response);
});
```

**Step 3: Parse the Raw Text as JSON**

Use the following example to parse the raw text to JSON:

```
const rawJSONText = response.match(/google\.visualization\.Query\.setResponse\(([\s\S\w]+)\)/); // strip the header response
const json = JSON.parse(rawJSONText[1]);
console.log(json);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: your solution requires the sheet to be shared publicly (anyone with the link). but it's not what I need.

actually I found a solution (I'll share it later). in a nutshell, you can follow this steps:

- connect the sheet to Firestore through google API key.

- implement a logic in Apps Script (using JavaScript) to save sheet data to Firestore, and updates whenever a change occurs in the sheet.

- now the angular app will deal with Firestore as the only source of data. and Apps Script code will feed Firestore with data whenever google sheet gets updated.


I hope I explained it well.